# How Do I Extract Just the Month and Year from a Full Date in SAS?

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc

How do I extract just the Month and Year from a full SAS date.  I know you can use the Year() and Month() functions, however, I would like to extract both at once.

Any suggestions?

For example my current date is 01/02/2018.  I would like to create a new column with 02/2018.

Thanks!

Comment: you want it as date or character value.

Comment: I would like it to be a date

Comment: you can use format instead, no need of new column

Comment: A SAS date always has all three elements, but you choose how to show them. Proc's such as Means/Freq will often respect the formats and summarize it according the format applied, however, PROC SQL will not group by the formatted values.

Comment: If you want a DATE value then it will have to be a specific day. Do you want to keep their current date or make them all use the same day of the month?   Which day of the month do you want?

Answer (score 3):

SAS stores dates as the number of days since 1960, so a date value is a specific day.  If you want all dates in the same month to appear the same then apply a date format that only displays the month and year (MONYYw., MMYYw., MMYYxw., etc.).  If you want all dates in the same month to be transformed to the same date then use the INTNX() function.  To transform `DATE` into `MONTH_YEAR` you could use this code.

```
month_year = intnx('month',date,0,'b');
```

And then attach your favorite format.

```
format month_year mmyys7. ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format` in a `proc sql` statement.  I think the format you want is::

```
proc sql;
    select datecol format = MMYYs7.
```

Comment: Format needs an `=` sign between - added it @Gordon Linoff - hope that's ok.